# What does "add" keyword do in a Ruby Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was looking over [ActionController::Renderers](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d54f0c52fa35565d2290638c706b6864bf097e00/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L155) and didn't understand the `add` in the following code:

```
    add :json do |json, options|
      json = json.to_json(options) unless json.kind_of?(String)

      if options[:callback].present?
        if media_type.nil? || media_type == Mime[:json]
          self.content_type = Mime[:js]
        end

        "/**/#{options[:callback]}(#{json})"
      else
        self.content_type = Mime[:json] if media_type.nil?
        json
      end
    end
```

Why do they use `add` in this context and what does it do?

Comment: `add` is just calling the `add` class method that is defined in [line 74 in the same file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d54f0c52fa35565d2290638c706b6864bf097e00/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L74).

Comment: it calls the `self.add` method on line 74 of that same file

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. For some reason, I was thinking that is some special Ruby keyword I was missing.